# Backbone Model isNew === true, even with ID assigned

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone model:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: '_id',

  url: '/api/user',

  defaults:
    { username: ''
    },

  initialize: function () {
    console.log(this, this.isNew());
  }
});
```

Then I initialise the model and fetch the instance:

```
var user = new User();

user.fetch();
```

This works. If I inspect `user`, there is an `id` property. It exists on the server. However, for some reason `user.isNew()` is reporting true - even though it has an `id` property set (property as well as attribute). I need to update this model on the server but Backbone insists on sending `POST` requests, when I need `PUT`…

Comment: you did not assign ID to the model, that's why. See my reply to your following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587217/backbone-model-save-is-causing-post-not-put/11587258#11587258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize runs before the fetch is completed. isNew value will change until the server answer arrives. Listen for the change event on the model or pass a callback to the fetch call.

```
var user = new User();

user.fetch({success : function(){
  console.log( user.isNew() );
}});
```

Comment: That's why! So where I'm saving to the model later in the application, I have `console.log`'d `isNew` and it returns false. But it still tries to make a POST request instead of a PUT… any idea why?

Comment: This is another question. May be you set other attribute as primary key or something like that. Could you create another question with your Model and save use case, paste sample code, so now we could verify the other issues. If isNew === false is supposed to do an update(Update) but seems like you have something broken in the middle of the way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587217/backbone-model-save-is-causing-post-not-put