# Backbone model.save() is causing POST not PUT

Tags: backbone.js

I have a Backbone model:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: '_id',

  url: '/api/user',

  defaults:
    { username: ''
    }
});
```

I fetch it:

```
var user = new User();

user.fetch();
```

Now, as an `click` event in one of my views, I have this:

```
toggleSubscription: function () {
  user.set('subscriptions', true);
  user.save();
}
```

This causes a POST request. However, the record already exists on the server, and since I fetched it (and the model instance has an `id` property), I thought that Backbone should do a PUT instead of a POST. Why might it be doing a POST instead?

Comment: Put this inside toggleSubscriptions: console.log( user.toJSON() ); and console.log( user.isNew() ); and paste here results please

Answer (score 7):

Try checking `user.isNew()`.

Looks like you created a new model which does not have an ID, that's why it's trying to add it during `Backbone.sync`.

**UPDATE:**

Above is exactly true. It does `POST` because it's a new model (which means, it does not have an id). Before you fetch a model, you need to give it an id. In your example:

```
var user = new User();
user.fetch();
user.save(); // in XHR console you see POST

var user = new User({ id: 123 });
user.fetch();
user.save(); // in XHR console you see PUT
```

Comment: Okay, but the ID is being fetched from the server. I don't know the ID of the user until I've fetched it. So what am I supposed to put as ID? I've checked and once it's fetched, `id` is an attribute and a property of `user`. `isNew` is equal to `false`. Can you explain that?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh no, id is NOT fetched from the server when you try to fetch a new model. Only when you fetch a collection your models will load with ids.

Comment: I don't understand that :( What's the difference between assigning an ID when instantiating `User` and fetching the user and getting an ID then?

Comment: If you have user id, and do `user = new User({ id: 123 })` fetch will work - without id it's always a new model. Like I said, when you fetch collection, it loads models with ids. But when you use `new User()` - it creates a new user model, and now you can only save it (via POST) - in which case it will get an id server side and be returned id POST is successful, and will update this new user model. After that you can do user.save() and it will do a PUT.

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain but I'm still lost. Why do you mention collections? I just don't get what the difference is between setting an ID when instantiating and having it set when you fetch. Can you try and explain in any other way, or link me to some potential answers/docs?

Comment: Well when you fetch, how do you want Backbone to know which model to load? Read this http://backbonejs.org/#Sync - you fetch always using GET, so you always need an ID: `read → GET   /collection[/id]` (same for models). Think about this - on the server side, when you read a specific record from database, you need primary key. Same here.

Comment: I think I'm with you, almost. Now I've given it an ID when instantiating `User`. Now, should fetch GET from `/api/user/:id`? Because it's still trying to GET from just `/api/user`.

Comment: It suggests to move this discussion to chat. In any case it's hard to tell without seeing more of your code.

Comment: You will see the `toggleSubscription` event method in `TimelineArticleView`.

Comment: I am also getting that issue. But when I run through, the type of method is PUT. I think it is because I'm using jquery-iframe-transport. How can I solve this one? It is happening in edit scenario but it is ok on create.

Answer (score 4):

> if the model does not yet have an id, it is considered to be new. --http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew

if the model does not yet have an id, it is considered to be new... AND therefore backbone will do a `PUT` request rather than a `POST`.

This behavior can be overridden simply by adding `type: 'POST'` to your save block:

```
var fooModel = new Backbone.Model({ id: 1});

fooModel.save(null, {
  type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: i guess it should be "will do a POST request rather a PUT" because we use POST method to add new objects and PUT method to update or modify them

Answer (score 2):

Use urlRoot property to set base URL `/api/user`. Then

1. it will POST to `/api/user` when you save a model which doesn't have `_id` property set 
   and
2. it will PUT to `/api/user/{_id}` when you save a model which has `_id` property set. Notice that it automatically  appends `_id` value to the base URL.

It will look for value of `_id` property because you have set that value to `idAttribute`.

Answer (score 1):

The server response must be in this way:

```
{
  _id : 111
}
```

Because you set _id as the primary key.  When model is fetched verify the value of _id it must have a value:
       console.log( model.get('_id') );

My thought is that you set in your backbone model '_id' as primary key, but service is returning you 'id'

**Update**: Adding sample code of normal behavior:

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: '_id',

  url: '/api/user',

  defaults:
    { username: ''
    }
});
user = new UserModel({_id : 20});
user.save();
user = new UserModel();
user.save();
```

Output:
PUT /api/user 405 (Method Not Allowed) 
POST /api/user 404 (Not Found)

Check how the first instance of the Model has an id and it tries to do the PUT but the other POST. I cannot reproduce your issue, so my thought is that the problem is on your server response.

Comment: I've set it to use `_id` by choice. `model.get('_id')` returns the ID, as does `model.id`.

Comment: I updated my answer, I tried your use case, using your model and I cannot reproduce your issue. Could you paste here your RAW server response? I think that there is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth checking if maybe [`emulateHTTP`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-emulateHTTP) is true. This will change all your PUT into POST with an added `_method` header (you may also want to check that this exists to confirm the idea).