# Backbone sync issue firing POST instead of PUT

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette

I have written the following code in my model:

```
 urlroot: '/url/sms',
setAuthId: function(value) {

    var _this = this ;

     if (this.get("smsauth") != value) {

        this.set("smsauth",value);
        this.save();

//Ideally, I want to achieve this AJAX call request with backbone.

         // $.ajax({
         //     url: "/url/sms",
         //     data: value,
         //     type: 'PUT',
         //     processData: false,
         //     success: function(result) {
         //        _this.set("authId", value);

         //     },
         //    error : function(){
         //        console.log('Error setting authid');
         //    }
         // });
     }

 },
```

Ideally, we should be firing a "PUT" request everytime. But the backbone is firing a POST request because "ID" is not present.

I'm quite new to backbone, I was wondering if there is anyway to sync with server without having to pass an ID? How can I solve this problem? 
**I basically want to fire a PUT request NOT post request for the URL.** (Since my backend only supports PUT request).

Comment: Where should I be adding this method? Should I be doing this.model.save({type:'PUT'}) but it still fires POST. Please tell me where do I put this method? @Sourabh-

Comment: Although it's a duplicate, it didn't got answered [backbone-model-save-is-causing-post-not-put](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587217/backbone-model-save-is-causing-post-not-put)

Comment: @DarkKnight. In your AJAX call like `data: value, method: 'PUT',`...

Comment: @Sourabh- my whole point is not to use .ajax calls but use backbone.save. I don't want to use ajax calls.  Is there anyway I can save and only fire PUT not post?

Comment: @dbf They are implicitly declaring an ID while creating the instance of the model. I have tried it but it fires API put request for /url/sms/1 (for id:1) which is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only real way to force `Backbone.Model.save()` to do a `PUT` is the way `@dbf` explained, you have to set your idAttribute. To properly set `idAttribute` your model *should* have an attribute that is unique. (This is not a hard requirement, since `model.isNew()` just checks that your model has a **property** named `id` or whatever string you supply to your model `idAttribute` property. It doesn't check for uniqueness).

I sense that in your case, you may not have a unique attribute in your models, so setting `idAttribute` may be a challenge. For that reason, I suggest you don't specify an `idAttribute` in your model definition. Rather, we just handle it dynamically.Just refactor your code like this:

```
setAuthId: function(value) {
    var _this = this ;

     if (this.get("smsauth") != value) {
        // any model attribute is fine, we just need to return a prop
        this.prototype.idAttribute = "smsauth" 
        this.save("smsauth",value) // Save will do a set before the server request
         // model.save returns a promise. Here we'll reset the idAttribute
         .then(/* success handler */ function (response) { 
             _this.set("authId",value);
             _this.prototype.idAttribute = 'id' // You can set this to "authId" if that 
                                                // uniquely identifies this model
         },/* error handler */  function (response) { 
             _this.prototype.idAttribute = 'id' // reset idAttribute to default
         });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear to me *what* you are saving. The fact you are handling with POST suggest its a new entry. Quoting from the [docs](http://backbonejs.org) this behaviour is correct. PUT is update, POST is create (under CRUD operations).

> If the model isNew, the save will be a "create" (HTTP POST), if the
>   model already exists on the server, the save will be an "update" (HTTP
>   PUT).

What you might try is what @Sami suggest by overwriting the save with an update request (do realise that all solutions here are incorrect/workarounds).

If you really need PUT and cannot alter your backend for some mysterious reason to accept POST, you could change the idAttribute within the model.

```
var smsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   idAttribute: "smsauth" // for example
});
```

Do realise that your backend, very likely, has a design flaw where you are changing and creating workarounds to work with it, which you should consider to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

I have used this snippet.

```
this.save({}, {
  type: 'PUT'
});
```

I found all your answers really fascinating, I am going to try everyone of them.

Thanks for your suggestions, this is why I like SO. Something new to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `save method`.
Something like

```
   var model = Backbone.Model.extend({

         save: function(options){
             return Backbone.sync("update", this, options);
         }


   });
```